# GRR windows client installation error: FleetspeakService failed to start

Tags: windows-services

I have started GRR server with docker in a kali linux and downloaded windows installation binary.

Then, when I'm trying to install GRR windows client (msi installer) I get following error:

[GRR windows client installation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Apfgz.png)

I have followed next steps to start the GRR server as a docker container: https://grr-doc.readthedocs.io/en/v3.4.6.7/installing-grr-server/via-docker.html

Here are windows 7 virtual machine details:
[windows7details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jppZK.png)

I have modified Group Policies (gpedit.msc) to allow my user logon services but the problem remains.

Also I have tried to install it in my local Windows 10 machine and I get the same error.

Also, I have tried to execute the msi installer as administrator without success.